# Is it possible to generate energy from the Van Allen radiation belt?

Tags: energy, space

I heard that the Van Allen belts are regions around the Earth with highly energetic charged particles, so I was wondering if it was possible to extract energy from them, and if so, how much?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a [particle flux of 10^7 cm^-2 s^-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Allen_radiation_belt#Flux_values) (high for most of the belts most of the time), with a mean energy of 10 MeV, the energy flux is about 160 mW/m^2, or about 0.01% of solar. Extracting energy from MeV charged particles is tougher than extraction it from solar photons. The radiation dose in the most intense parts of the belts is hard on electronics and sensors, so we try to avoid orbits that pass through there.

Solar panels are far, far, more practical.